# Java jar executable cannot read excel files on dropbox

Tags: java, excel, dropbox, executable-jar

A bit complex issue.

I have a program to read data from excel files using XSSFSheets. Everything works fine.

The problem i have is that for some users the program does not work if the files is located on dropbox. (Local version of dropbox, on their hard drive.)

The issue is not path related. Checked more times than i can count.

What is strange is that everyone has exactly the same admin rights for dropbox and office 365. The only difference i can find so far is that these users has windows 10.

If we place these excel files on the desktop, the program can find them.

Does anyone know if there is an issue for Java get excel sheets on dropbox for any reason? Can it have anything to do with windows 10 resp windows 8? If so why does it work on the windows 10 desktop.

Comment: `the program does not work` what exactly do you mean with that? what is the error?

Comment: (1) (already checked) User centric folders and internationalized folders have a displayed path and an actual path. The Dropbox folder has its own icon and resides in the user's directory. Can you do a directory listing and file copy in java? (2) XSSF, though a nice format, seems slow, and Excel formats are varying; could it be the files/versions? (3) Some virus protection / dropbox synchronisation running?

Comment: Hi reading the excel file does not work if it is located on dropbox. Using HSSF

The program runs, and all functions work, but it cannot retrieve any information from the excel data sheets.

Comment: Are you using Smart Sync, and if so does setting the files to "local" fix the problem?  This should happen automatically when your app tries to access them, but maybe there's a Java-related subtlety there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone that answered.

I finally found out what was wrong.

The computors that run just Java JRE could not run the program.

Computors that ran Java JDK could. So it seems that i have used some function only available for developers. I dont know what exactly but issue solved, so I'm not going to put more effort to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class xlmsReader {

    public static ArrayList<XSSFSheet> fileReader() {

        String directPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        //removing the folder name, search through all folders in the parent folder, regardless of the location of the program folder.
        directPath = directPath.substring(0, directPath.length()-18);

        File[] directories = new File(directPath).listFiles(File::isDirectory);

        ArrayList<XSSFSheet> excel = new ArrayList<XSSFSheet>();

        for (int j = 0; j < directories.length; j++) {


            if (new File(directories[j] + "\\Groning.xlsm").exists()) {

                String str = directories[j] + "\\Groning.xlsm";

                FileInputStream file;
                file = null;
                try {
                    file = new FileInputStream(new File(str));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                XSSFWorkbook workbook;
                workbook = null;
                try {
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Gröning");
                sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue(directories[j].getPath());
                excel.add(sheet);

            }
        }
        return excel;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code im using, i expect that i get one of the 2 exception when i try to read the file. I realise now that maybe i should try to send the exception to the gui in case of them happening.